# Xamarin Studio cannot find Android tools/devices

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

After installing Xamarin Studio, I've found it to miss Android related items such as Android SDK Manager under `Tools` menu:

[image]

Additionally I cannot run the application on an actual device, nor see any emulator:
[image]

Please note that I've developed Android app using Eclipse prior to this so I have everything properly setup (including device driver, ADB, Android SDK/NDK, etc), and have also made Xamarin Studio work on another computer. The problem is that it refuses to work on this particular computer, and uninstall/install it didn't help.

How do I fix it so that Android tools are shown in Tools menu and I can run Xamarin applications on an emulator/actual device?

Comment: You are on Windows right? Did you install XS from here? http://xamarin.com/download

Comment: @DavidKarlaš yes, and ended with this exact same problem, so I uninstall only Xamarin Studio and reinstall only Xamarin Studio, didn't help

Comment: @DavidKarlaš And I have to say Xamarin Installer is extremely buggy. It've already installed x86 JDK1.6 by the same installer previously, but it would try to download JDK1.6 and failed to install it, forcing me to manually uninstall JDK/JRE 1.6 first.

Comment: Have you pointed Xamarin in the right direction? 
Xamarin Studio > Tools > Options > SDK Locations

Comment: @Bart yeah, all the setting was correct, turned out to be bad install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following steps resolved the issue for me:

1. Uninstall Xamarin Studio
2. Uninstall x86 JRE/JDK 1.6 installed by Xamarin Installer
3. Run Xamarin Installer and let it reinstall both JRE/JDK & Xamarin Studio

Don't know why the Xamarin installation wasn't working correctly the first time, nor why the above steps work, but it worked.